# Can't figure out why PHP file doesn't get called by Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this is my Code inside a html file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (event)
    {
        $(document).on("click", ".interestbutton", function(e)
        {
            var docID = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "interest.php",
                data: {docID },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("done");
                }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

The "console.log" works but nothing inside my php file does. Any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: if `console.log("done")` is working then the problem must be in the php file. Could you post it?

Comment: for testing purposes I deleted anything except an 'echo' statement. still doesn't work!

Comment: Could you post it?

Comment: <?php
    echo 'inside php file';
 ?>

Comment: And what do you get with `console.log(data)` in your success function? What happens when you navigate directly to interest.php? Did you double check the path to the file? Is there a .htaccess file in the directory?

Comment: Huh, console.log(data) gives me the string from my echo statement. I'm 100% sure the path is correct. It's in the root directory of my project and other php files inside this directory work fine. No .htaccess file.

Comment: well, if `console.log(data)` gives you the string from your echo statement, that means the php file is being run.

Answer (score 1):

Change `data: {docID }` for `data: {docID: docID}` as it is an object.

Comment: thanks! But for some reason it still doesn't work. Really not sure what I'm doing wrong, other php files work without a problem for me.